# Google Play - API to get sales informations

Tags: google-play, report

On **Google Play Console**, it's possible to manually download a .csv sales report (menu Download reports > Financial).

Cause I would like to make a automatic process, do you know if there is a **API** that allows you to directly get this sales information?

Comment: did you find a solution to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

As described [on the help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017) you can use all of the Google Cloud Storage APIs and tools (including `gsutil`) to download these programmatically from [Google Cloud Storage](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export).

Comment: any example of REST GET request to retrieve earnings info?

Comment: That article mentions only about manual and gsutil ways. There is no API at that page